# how to run SSRS reports using SSIS?

Tags: ssis, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSISpackage which have 10 execute sql tasks, which loads data into the 10 tabales. Using these 10 tables, I load
data into 2 tables. These 2 tables are using to generate reports using SSRS. So we have creatad SSRS package which will generate report. So here what we are doing is we are loading data into 
those (10+2) tables. then running that report manually and sending that created excel report manully. Can we achieve this using SSIS only, so once data loaded into those 2 reporting table it will start generating reports. How do we achieve using SSRS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you just adding all the possible SSRS tags?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Maybe remove the tags which aren't related, as it might be important. Also, are you using Standard, BI, or Enterprise edition?

Comment: Hi Jo,
            I am using sql server 2012 and Enterprise edition.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this to generate SSRS reports using SSIS - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/93504/