# Run SSRS report via SSIS using ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssis

How do I run a SSRS report using VS2015 in a SSIS package. The following answer is not the latest way of doing this apparently from what I have read. This post is the old way
[how to run SSRS reports using SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439730/how-to-run-ssrs-reports-using-ssis) because it mentions ReportExecutionService not ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient.

I also tried another sites answer when I call the proxy (like first line of code it fails.

```
var webServiceProxy = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient("ReportExecutionServiceSoap")
```

Error I get is:
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find endpoint element with name 'ReportExecutionServiceSoap' and contract 'ServiceReference1.ReportExecutionServiceSoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

It does not matter if I use the default config or the one from the below example or if I call the constructor that does not require a endpoint, so I am lost what else to try.

Refer to:
[C# Example in SSIS](http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/26/executing-reporting-services-web-service-from-asp-net-mvc-using-wcf-add-service-reference.aspx)

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://<myserver>/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx?WSDL"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig"
        contract="ServiceReference1.ReportExecutionServiceSoap" name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Also at design time there is a warning:

```
The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The value 'ServiceReference1.ReportExecutionServiceSoap' is invalid according to its datatype 'clientContractType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.
```

Comment: Try removing the ?WSDL suffix from the endpoint address: `http://meldc1cdbtst2v/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx`

Comment: The end point is in the first line of code "ReportExecutionServiceSoap"!?

Comment: I tried with and without the ?WSDL

Comment: what happens if you point your browser to the endpoint address, including the ?WDL suffix? Is should show some xml. Also, what happens if you set the address in code like `webServiceProxy.Url = "http://<myserver>/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx"`

Comment: Correct it opens the wsdl file, if it did not open then I would assume there would be no code generated for ServiceReference1

Comment: You can take a look at a project a created a while ago to see how I did the connection. See https://reportservermanager.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Logic/RS2005Facade.cs

Comment: I still think your example code is using a Web Reference as opposed to a Service Reference!? How do I generate the ReportingService2005 class?

Comment: Well, if I remember correctly I used the [wsdl tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I found a solution that works here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3475/execute-a-sql-server-reporting-services-report-from-integration-services-package/ which incidentally is the easier code base to follow. Might have another go with this code base another day and start from scratch.